# Библиотеки для графиков

Tags: java, android

Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки для работы с графиками на Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open source библиотека **Graph View**. [Сайт](http://www.android-graphview.org/) | [GitHub](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView)
- **MPAndroidChart** - open source, поддерживаем множество видов графиков. [GitHub](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)
- **Androidplot** - open source, также поддерживает множество видов графиков. [Сайт](http://androidplot.com/) | [GitHub](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot) | [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/androidplot/androidplot)
- **HelloCharts**. [GitHub](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android)
- Платная библиотека **Chart**. [Сайт](http://www.telerik.com/android-ui/chart)
- Платная библиотека **aiCharts**. [Сайт](http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/aiCharts.aspx)